# Kotlin coroutine in Dispatchers.Main doesn't block main thread

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this code:

```
override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            println(1)
            delay(3000)
            println(2)
        }
        println(3)
    }
```

Instead of `delay`, there can be any blocking operation.

`Dispatchers.Main` does not have a thread pool? The stream should be blocked. Why is the output like this: `3 -> 1 -> 2`. And not `1 -> 2 -> 3`? Also `viewModelscope` by default works on `Dispatchers.Main`

Help me figure it out

Comment: To be honest, I'm not exactly sure what is your question. `launch()` launches the code block concurrently to the caller, so technically speaking, we don't have guarantees if `1` or `3` execute the first. In practice though, it will be usually `3` in the current implementation of coroutines. And the queue is not blocked, because `delay()` doesn't block the thread - it suspends the coroutine, which is a different thing. If you put `Thread.sleep()` there, your application will freeze.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change your code to:

```kotlin
override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main.immediate) {
            println(1)
            delay(3000)
            println(2)
        }
        println(3)
    }
```

...then you will get closer to your expected output — at least in Kotlin/JS, you get `1`, then `3`, then `2`.

The difference between `Dispatchers.Main.immediate` and `Dispatchers.Main` is very similar to the difference between `runOnUiThread()` on `Activity` and `post()` on `View`. Both of those methods take a `Runnable` and run that `Runnable` on the main application thread. However, that main application thread's primary job is to do work posted to a work queue.

- `post()` puts the `Runnable` on that queue, and returns immediately
- `runOnUiThread()` sees if our code is executing *right now* on the main application thread, and if it is, `runOnUiThread()` runs the `Runnable` immediately — if the `runOnUiThread()` call is made on a background thread, though, it behaves like `post()`

`Dispatchers.Main` puts the coroutine on the work queue. That coroutine will not run until sometime later. Since `onResume()` is called on the main application thread, and since the coroutine will run later, `println(3)` executes first.

`Dispatchers.Main.immediate` says "if our code is executing on the main application thread, run the coroutine immediately", much like `runOnUiThread()` does. Since `onResume()` is called on the main application thread, at least `println(1)` will be called before `println(3)`.

**UPDATE: 2023-09-22**: The actual implementation of `Dispatchers.Main` and `Dispatchers.Main.immediate` are platform-specific, and that may have an impact on how `delay()` is handled. On Kotlin/JS (and probably in Kotlin/JVM based on [Ian Lake's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77154119/kotlin-coroutine-in-dispatchers-main-doesnt-block-main-thread/77154147?noredirect=1#comment136014999_77154147)), `delay()` will schedule the rest of the coroutine to run later and free up the current thread. This allows the main application thread to continue processing past the `launch()` call, so `println(3)` happens, and `println(2)` occurs at the 3-second mark. You would want to test the behavior in other Kotlin Multiplatform targets to ensure that it works the same there.

Comment: TIL about `Dispatchers.Main.immediate` nice! :-)

Comment: The `delay` will still delay the print of `3` (since `delay` does not block any thread at all, just schedules a callback for that time), so you'll still get 1, 3, then 2, right?

Comment: @ianhanniballake: Ah, good point, I missed that nuance. I so rarely nowadays do this kind of "code golf" and I was working from memory. I'll update the answer -- thanks!

Answer (score 1):

https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-main.html

> On Native Darwin-based targets, it is a dispatcher backed by Darwin's main queue.

This is because the main thread on Android is a queue based system.

Your co-routine is added to the queue and the queue is already running the code in onResume, so that finishes first.